# Backup e Restore em Delphi com Sql Server como fazer?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, delphi, backup

Olá gostaria de saber como posso fazer um Backup e Restore para integrar em meu sistema. Eu tenho um código pronto mas é para firebird acredito que não sirva para Sql Server. Li em alguns tópicos que não existem componentes para Backup e Restore com Sql Server no Delphi, as únicas maneiras de fazer seria via linha de código, em outro artigo achei algo a respeito de fazer uma procedure no banco de dados e chama - la no Delphi. O meu grande problema e que nunca fiz uma procedure no banco e nem é muito a minha especialidade banco de dados. Por fim gostaria de saber se podem me da uma ajuda a desenvolver um Backup e Restore para sistema Delphi usando Sql Server 2012

Comment: Como assim, você quer fazer backup e restore mas não é sua especialidade Banco de Dados? Chegou a hora de expandir suas especialidades.

Comment: Sim, estou expandindo, mas venho do ambiente web onde minha função quase nunca se conectava com banco de dados, agora no ambiente desktop estou sempre em contato e estou expandindo. Mas o que eu descrevi na pergunta por exemplo, é algo novo para mim.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TBackupRestore.BtnBackUpClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ADOCommand : TADOCommand;
  CLIENTE : String;
begin

  CLIENTE := 'teste';

  ADOCommand := TADOCommand.Create(nil); //Cria o objeto de comando para executar a rotina de backup do SQL SERVER 2000
  with ADOCommand do begin
    //ADOCommand.Name := 'ADOGeraBackup'; //Nome do objeto
    ADOCommand.ConnectionString := ADOConnection1.ConnectionString; //Cria a conexão com o Provider do SQL Server
    //ADOCommand.CommandType := cmdText; //Define como command Text para execução de linhas de comando
    ADOCommand.CommandText := 'BACKUP DATABASE '+CLIENTE+' TO DISK =''c:\SQLBackUp\sql.bak''';
    ADOCommand.Execute; //Executa a linha de comando
  end;

end;
```

o Restore vai ser parecido, porém você terá que trabalhar um código para executar primeiro em uma tabela de testes, vai da trabalho, mas se quebrar a cabeça creio que você consegue !